# Cannot define a function calling 'worklet': "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm learning React Native Reanimated version 2, but I got an issue when creating a function that calls `'worklet'`.

I installed React Native Reanimated version 2 on a React Native **bare project** that was created with `npx react-native init myApp`. 
I have followed all the installation instructions, as follows.

- Configuring the `babel.config.js` :

```js
    module.exports = {
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      plugins: [
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
      ]
    };
```

- Enabling [Hermes](https://hermesengine.dev/), setting it to true.
- Configuring the `MainApplication.java` file.
- Cleaning the build.
- Resetting the cache using `yarn start --reset-cache`.

I try to make a simple [Worklet](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/fundamentals/worklets) function like this:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

    const App = () => {

      const someWorklet = () => {
        'worklet';
        console.log('this run on UI thread');
      };

      return (
        <View >
          <Button title="Press" onPress={() => { }} />
        </View>
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

As you can see, the code in `App.js` is simple, but when I call `'worklet'`, I always get an `undefined is not a function` error as shown below.

[image: error message]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ohh i feel like a stupid man...

I just need to import the `react-native-reanimated` in the `App.js` and all done.. :)

```
import 'react-native-reanimated'
```

It looks like the react-native-reanimated v2 documentation doesnt mention to import the `react-native-reanimated` on to the top of our project...

Comment: Not just you, everyone here should be feeling stupid haha, thanks!